# Doesn't gsl::cstring_span support constexpr? If not, why should I use it?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, ms-gsl

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
constexpr gsl::cstring_span<> const somestring{"Hello, I am a string"};
```

and it refuses to compile with a message complaining that some non-constexpr function is being called somewhere.

Why is this? This seems like the most important use-case to support. The whole point is to have compile-time bounds checking if at all possible. Compile time bounds checking involving constant string literals seems like the thing it would be used for the most often. But this can't happen if it can't be declared `constexpr`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that string literals have type array of `const char` and are null-terminated. But who is to say you are constructing your `cstring_span` from a null-terminated array?

Because of that the constructor of `cstring_span` does a physical check to remove the null terminator if it exists, otherwise accept the full length of the array.

I am not sure how powerful `constexpr` expressions can be but it *may* be possibly to implement it in a `constexpr` way. You could create an issue asking about it here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/issues

Comment: Your answer gave me a clue, and I realized we should be using `czstring_span` instead and then we don't have the problem. The other issue is that MSVC doesn't really handle complex constexpr things very well. This is where its C++17 support is the most lacking. gcc and clang are fully capable of handling removing the terminating null in a constexpr way.